# "Please remove DXGIDebug.dll from folder C:\WINDOWS\SysWOW64. It is unsecure to run CL.exe until it is done

Tags: c, visual-studio, visual-studio-2015, visual-studio-2017, cl.exe

I cannot compile any C project in Visual Studio, I always get the error:

> Please remove DXGIDebug.dll from folder C:\WINDOWS\SysWOW64. It is unsecure to run CL.exe until it is done.

I got this error before in Visual Studio 2015 and after trying to repair the installation several times I decided to install VIsual Studio 2017 but the issue persists.

I have got another PC with the same installation and it works fine there. I have already checked if the DLL is corrupted or shouldn't be there but the other PC has the exact same file in the exact same place and it works. I couldn't find anything regarding this issue or anything similar on the internet, as I do not know what to do now to be able to compile a C project.

Comment: So did you try to just, uhm, remove the offending file?

Comment: I suggest that you back the file up and get rid of it

Comment: Well, the thing is I can't remove it because its a system file and always in use. Didn't get to install and boot another OS, yet, as I thought there has to be another solution. And because it's present on my other PC as well, I thought it wouldn't be such a good idea to remove it.

Comment: With a lot of hassle I was finally able to delete the file even if it was protected. Now when I try to compile I get an error in the error list that says
"LNK1104" cannot open file 'Debug\Main.obj'"

Obviously my Main.c still doesn't get compiled.